# Asp.net - Session Timeout Windows

Tags: asp.net

We got few legacy apps developed in DotNet 1.0/2.0. We want to implement session timeout for these applications.

So if user hasn't done any activity for 20 mins, pop up window should come up saying whether you want to keep the session active or not - if not then log me off, else keep his session active.

Please help as Im new to DotNet.

Regards

Comment: Just from a reasoning point of view, If a user haven't done anything for 20 min then do you think your pop-up confirmation window will be answered ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can set the timeout for your Asp.Net application by adding this code under system.web tag in web.config file**

**Form Authentication:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="Validation" timeout="20"/>
</authentication>
```

**Windows Authentication:**

Note:If the users are logging onto a windows environment and it is controled by active directory (domain) there is the chance that there is a domain policy in place to log the user out of the "windows session" after so many minutes of inactivity, this would be done for security reasons.  I think your next step would be to talk with whoever is in charge with the windows network and pass it off to them.

**And for the second part**

> So if user hasn't done any activity for 20 mins, pop up window should
>   come up saying whether you want to keep the session active or not - if
>   not then log me off, else keep his session active.

**, Below is the link please go through this there you will find a complete Solution of your problem.**

[http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout.aspx)

Thanks & Regards,
Subhankar

Answer (score 0):

If you application is using Master Pages or your pages are inherited from some custom page class than it will be easy for you otherwise you will have to code in every page.

When a user is logged into your application, put his login Id in some cookie, then in your master page, custome page class or all pages do something like:

```
if(Session["SOMEVARIABLE"] == null)
{
      //show your dialuge to user
}
```

if user selects to keep the session active than pick his/her login Id from cookie, call your login mechanism again and log him/her into application otherwise redirect him/her to login page.